# Running jdbc on top of multiple port forwarding

Tags: java, jdbc, exec, tunnel, plink

When I want to access the database, there is an architecture through which I need to tunnel my connection. So, when I have to use a GUI tool like MySQL Workbench, i have to open three Putty sessions.
I am trying to do the same using Java. So I am using Runtime exec to run plink. This is working fine, I am able to establish the connection and send some unix commands to it and retrieve the output.
I want to run jdbc on top of it. Is it possible. Since, the putty sessions are running in the background, do the port forwarding rules apply to the jdbc I will be running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will run if you set up the tunnels correct.

Comment: I was not sure how exactly nested tunnels work. Thanks!